# Java ActiveMQ + STOMP + SSH: illegal reflective access operation to method sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.setHost

Tags: java, activemq-classic, stomp, amazon-mq

I'm writing a simple Java JMS QueueBrowser client to **AmazonMQ**, that runs **ActiveMQ** with `stomp` protocol over `ssh` (hence he transport is `stomp+ssl`:

```
// java
import java.util.Enumeration;

// jms
import javax.jms.IllegalStateException;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.jms.QueueBrowser;
import javax.jms.QueueSession;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.Connection;

// activemq
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;

public class QueueBrowserExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("init");
        try {

            final String PORT = "61616";
            final String PROTOCOL = "stomp+ssl";
            final String HOST = "xxx.mq.us-east-1.amazonaws.com";
            final String connectionString = PROTOCOL + "://" + HOST + ":" + PORT;

            System.out.println("attempt to connect to " + connectionString);

            ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(connectionString);
            Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection("admin", "admin");
            connection.start();
            Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            Queue queue = session.createQueue("Test");
            QueueBrowser queueBrowser = session.createBrowser(queue);
            Enumeration msgs = queueBrowser.getEnumeration();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting then a `javax.jms.JMSException` execepion due to the Transport used (`stomp+ssl` I assume)

```
javax.jms.JMSException: Could not create Transport. Reason: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid connect parameters: {wireFormat.host=b-02b566af-1f0d-4d48-ad24-229a813a53fb-1.mq.us-east-1.amazonaws.com}
        at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:36)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createTransport(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:319)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:332)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:253)
        at QueueBrowserExample.main(QueueBrowserExample.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid connect parameters: {wireFormat.host=b-02b566af-1f0d-4d48-ad24-229a813a53fb-1.mq.us-east-1.amazonaws.com}
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFactory.doConnect(TransportFactory.java:122)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFactory.connect(TransportFactory.java:64)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createTransport(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:317)
        ... 3 more
```

The ActiveMQ back-end is using STOMP, and I do not have any access to it. Hence I have to figure how to "manage" the queue (watching messages only, not processing), and I came to QueueBrowser and JMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JMS over STOMP is not supported.

Keep in mind that JMS is just an API. The underlying wire protocol is different between most brokers. In ActiveMQ "Classic" (which is what Amazon MQ uses) you can use JMS via the OpenWire protocol or via AMQP (which requires using Qpid JMS library). There is no support for JMS over STOMP.

In this case, you're using the OpenWire JMS client since you're using `org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory`. It doesn't matter what you specify in the connection string, the client will use the OpenWire protocol.

STOMP just doesn't support much of the functionality exposed by JMS. Queue browsers in particular are not supported by STOMP.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I missed that. So there is any alternative when using `stomp` it seems, unless implementing a message receiver client (a watcher then) and the auto acknowledgement off on the server. Or maybe there is an alternative library in Python/NodeJS. For sure AWS SDK do not implement a `QueueBrowser`.

Comment: Thanks I did know about JMS OpenWire, I supposed that it was cross-protocol sort of. STOMP is the server protocol, cannot change that. Thanks.

Comment: Ye the ActiveMQ backend is using STOMP, and I do not have any access to it. Hence I have to figure how to “‘manage” the queue (watching messages only, not processing) and I came to QueueBroker and JMS. Thank you.

Comment: Add on. The problem here with STOMP seems to be related to https://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-unack-the-message-with-stomp