# How to get pending ActiveMQ messages?

Tags: node.js, activemq-classic, stomp

I am working on a Socket.IO application that consumes messages from an ActiveMQ queue. I am using STOMP library for Node.js.

I can send and receive messages from the queue, but I want to get the list of pending messages that were already in the queue. Is there a way to achieve this using STOMP? If not can anyone point me to another library that can give me the pending message details.

```js
const Stomp = require("stomp-client");
const client = new Stomp("localhost", 61613);

client.connect((sessionId) => {
  console.log(` receiver connected successfully.`);
  client.subscribe("/queue/PENDING", onMessageCallback);
});

const onMessageCallback = (body, headers) => {
  console.log(` ~ onMessageCallback ~ body:`, body);
  console.log(` ~ onMessageCallback ~ headers:`, headers);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the ActiveMQ Messages REST API.

FYI-- the STOMP protocol supports browse, and there are ActiveMQ server-side browse implementation present, but my quick scan did not see a unit test for it specifically. You might fire up a broker and add the BROWSER option to subscribe to see if it 'just works'.

Comment: To be clear, the STOMP protocol itself doesn't support message browsing. That functionality would be implementation specific.

Comment: Alternatives to JMS Queue Browser for STOMP over ActiveMQ: Via Jolokia protocol -> HTTP-JMX  bridge it has various browse methods . Hope we can read the pending messages . Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71383792/alternatives-to-jms-queue-browser-for-stomp-over-activemq